# Resizing a PowerShell window on a remote computer using a batch file

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, scripting

Wondering if anyone knows how to/if it is even possible to resize a PowerShell windows that I open on a remote computer using the batch file I used to run it.

```
1   @ECHO OFF 
2   title Remote Start ProgramName Server
3   cd "C:\IT\FOLDER"
4  
5   @ECHO OFF
6   SET /p _computer=Computer Name:
7
8   @ECHO "Launching Program Server On Remote PC %_computer%"
9
10  start PowerShell.exe .\psexec -i \\%_computer% '"C:\Program Files\ProgramFolder\programserver.exe"'
11  
12  @ECHO "Launching ClientSideProgram on Local Machine"
13  start "" "C:\Program Files\ProgramFolder\programclient.exe"
14
15  PAUSE
16
17  start "" PowerShell.exe .\pskill \\%_computer% programserver.exe
18  ECHO "Program Server Terminated"
19
20  PAUSE
```

So as far as I have tested this, it works, but when I do start PowerShell.exe on line 10, it, as expected opens a powershell. THIS is the powershell I would like to resize to the smallest possible size, so that it's not as big of a nuisance when it opens.

Thanks in advance for whatever help anyone has

Edit: If resizing is not possible, can I just 'hide' it? or move it to the background at all?

Comment: What are you using [tag:PowerShell] for? and why with `Start`

Comment: psexec is a powershell tool so I thought I'd have to go the rout of using powershell. The reason I need start is because I want these 2 programs to launch simultaneously. I do not want to wait for the server to close before the client open. If I don't include the start, it will open the server, and just hang on that block, not until server close will it continue to next bit @Compo

Comment: [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), and [PsKill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) are not PowerShell speific utilities, _the `PS` in the name has no relationship to PowerShell_.

Comment: omitting PowerShell.exe fails to launch the program on the remote computer. Unless you can explain to me how come, or in which way to rewrite this script, it is a necessity for it to function like I intend it to I believe

Comment: Did you bother to read the usage information for both of the utilities, it's available in the two linked pages, from my previous comment. You'll also note that the latest versions are still compatible with Windows Vista, which you should know does not carry `PowerShell`, and neither of those pages so much as give `PowerShell` a mention. You could alternatively open a `cmd.exe` window and enter `PsExec` and `PsKill -` to read their help information. When the information appears in `cmd.exe`, you will note that both utilities work without any requirement on `PowerShell`. Please provide feedback.

Comment: For someone who I would imagine is genuinely trying to help, you're coming off awfully rude and patronizing with your approach. Regardless, thanks for the help and taking time out to comment. I think it's pretty much an answered question in regards to this small issue, much to learn still though. @Compo

Answer (score 1):

This is a batch file that is just using PowerShell to call psexec.

Either use PowerShell Remoting ---

[Running Remote Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6)

> Start an Interactive Session To start an interactive session with a
>   single remote computer, use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet. For example,
>   to start an interactive session with the Server01 remote computer,
>   type:

```
Enter-PSSession Server01
```

> Run a Remote Command To run a command on one or more computers, use
>   the Invoke-Command cmdlet. For example, to run a Get-UICulture command
>   on the Server01 and Server02 remote computers, type:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -ScriptBlock {Get-UICulture}
```

--- or use PSexec and target that remote host.

[PsExec - Windows Sysinternals | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Using psExec to Open a Remote Command Window
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/systemcenteressentials/2009/09/01/using-psexec-to-open-a-remote-command-window

psExec \computer cmd

[PsExec (SysInternals)](https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)
Execute a command-line process on a remote machine.

Much of PSRemoting requires that you use an account that is in the local admin group on the target. However, there are some that do not.

The only reason to use PSExec over PSRemoting is if PSRemoting is not enabled and if you need to run Code in the context of the logged on user.

```
# PowerShell only via PSRemoting
$TargetComputerName  = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a computer name.'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetComputerName -ScriptBlock {
'C:\Program Files\ProgramFolder\programserver.exe'
} -Credential 'contoso\administrator'

# PSExec only
psexec \SomeTargetComputerName -c C:\Program Files\ProgramFolder\programserver.exe
```

With PSRemoting nothing is ever displayed on the targethost.
With that PSExec command, nothing is ever displayed on the targethost.

If you use PSExec to run in the context of the logged on user on that target host, then stuff will display when you call PowerShell.exe unless you use the [minimize or hide switches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pToo7J1BuY).

This indicates that you are new to PowerShell and PowerShell remoting commands. Please hit up YouTube and view some of the talks on [PSRemoting](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell%20remoting), [running remote command](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell%20run%20remote%20command), [running remote programs](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell%20run%20remote%20programs), well, [PowerShell in general.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell%20beginning)

Comment: Certainly new to PowerShell, I never claimed knowledge, just sort of doing whatever small work is needed whilst learning a lot, thanks for the in depth clarification. I do know that PSRemoting is disabled, which is what lead me to find and ultimately use PsExec.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from a fellow colleague of mine. Apparently, very easy to just star minimized.

```
start /MIN
```

will do just that